# What happens to the iOS KeyChain when iPhone OS is updated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

A user of my App who upgraded from iOS 5.1 to 6.0 is hitting some NSAsserts that could only happen if the keychain data was critically corrupted.
I can't tell exactly but it seems the keyChain data is not maintained between upgrades.